# Updating pandas dataframe with value equal to sum of same df and another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datframes that look like this

```
df1

posting_period      name        sales       profit
    1               client1     50.00       10.00
    1               client2     100.00      20.00
    2               client1     150.00      30.00

df2 (this df does not have the 'profit' column as in df1) 

posting_period      name        sales       
    1               client1     10.00       
    2               client1     20.00
```

I want to update the sales in `df1` for client1 with the sum of client1's sales in `df1` and client1's sales in `df2` where the posting_periods match. In other words

```
desired result

posting_period      name        sales       profit
    1               client1     60.00       10.00
    1               client2     100.00      20.00
    2               client1     170.00      30.00
```

The actual dataframes I'm working with are much larger, but these examples capture what I'm trying to accomplish. I came up with a very round-about way that  not only didn't work, it wasn't very pythonic. The other challenge is the additional column in `df1` not in `df2`. I was hoping someone could suggest an alternative. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a series from `df2` mapping index columns to `sales`:

```
idx_cols = ['posting_period', 'name']
s = df2.set_index(idx_cols)['sales']
```

Then update `df1['sales']` using this series:

```
df1['sales'] += pd.Series(df1.set_index(idx_cols).index.map(s.get)).fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

   posting_period     name  sales  profit
0               1  client1   60.0    10.0
1               1  client2  100.0    20.0
2               2  client1  170.0    30.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join for aligned `Series` and last [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
s = df1.merge(df2, on=['posting_period','name'], how='left')['sales_y']

df1['sales'] = df1['sales'].add(s, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
   posting_period     name  sales  profit
0               1  client1   60.0    10.0
1               1  client2  100.0    20.0
2               2  client1  170.0    30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `pd.concat` with `sum`

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index(['posting_period', 'name']),df2.set_index(['posting_period', 'name'])],1).sum(level=0,axis=1).reset_index()
Out[728]: 
   posting_period     name  sales  profit
0               1  client1   60.0    10.0
1               1  client2  100.0    20.0
2               2  client1  170.0    30.0
```